# .htaccess redirect up one level

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, wildcard

I have modified our Wordpress website structure slightly, and end up with 404 errors on pages like these

```
http://www.feature-fire.co.uk/products-2/feed/?product_tag=barbas
http://www.feature-fire.co.uk/products-2/feed/?product_cat=stoves-multifuel
http://www.feature-fire.co.uk/products-2/feed/?product_cat=type-fires
```

Tried the following redirect:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/products-2/feed/.*$ http://www.feature-fire.co.uk/products-2/
```

, i.e. back to /products-2/ page, but not working.

Can anyone help me on this one?

Comment: Can you post your existing WP .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following instead:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /products-2/feed/ http://www.feature-fire.co.uk/products-2/
```